# What is the point of creating method reference from already exiting implementation of functional interface (like via anonymous class)?

Tags: java, anonymous, functional-interface

```
interface Foo<T> {
    T apply(T double1, T double2);
}

public class Test {
    static void calculate(Double double1, Double double2, Foo<Double> func) {
        double result = func.apply(double1, double2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double double1 = 100;
        double double2 = 0.2;
        calculate(double1, double2, new Foo<Double>() {
            
            public Double apply(Double double1, Double double2) {
                return double1 * (1+double2);
            }
        }::apply);
       //^^^^^^^---- does it improve anything? (code will work without it)
    }
}
```

I don't understand the use of the syntax `::apply` at the end of the anonymous class's construction. I don't understand why this doesn't cause a compilation error and I don't understand what it achieves.

If you remove `::apply`, the program works. So why use double colons in this instance?

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo. However, this explains the use of double colon which I understand but I don't understand why it has been added to the end of an anonymous class when it doesn't need to be there. If you remove ::apply the program still works so why put it there in the first place.

Comment: In that case I would suggest to use [edit] option to clarify your question. Otherwise I am afraid that some people will simply mark it as duplicate of question I provided in first comment (which will prevent new answers to be posted here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a poor use of the `::` operator. It's quite silly to explicitly construct an anonymous `Foo<Double>` instance just to turn around and use `::apply` to extract the `apply()` implementation and create a *second* anonymous function object. It uses two equivalent idioms at the same time. One will do.

As you say, it would be more sensible to leave off `::apply` and use the anonymous object directly:

```
calculate(double1, double2, new Foo<Double>() {
    public Double apply(Double double1, Double double2) {
        return double1 * (1+double2);
    }
});
```

Or ditch the anonymous `Foo<Double>` class and use 100% lambda syntax:

```
calculate(double1, double2, (a, b) -> a * (1 + b));
```

The latter would be my preference since it is so much more concise.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent explanation - code came from a reputable source so I was really confused.